# Shortcut key to forward email to fixed email address in Postbox

Tags: postbox

As an avid user of todo apps (currently Asana) is very much miss a way to easily forward an email from Postbox to my GTD app. Currently the workflow is:

- Click cmd/L to open the forward email window
- Type x@mail.asana in the To: address field
- Click the send button in the forward email window

What I would like to have is an automator or applescript that does that for me. Ex: Highligh/select the mail I wish to convert to a task in Asana and the type a shortcut like ctrl/cmd/L to forward the mail to Asana.

As most todo apps have custom email addresses you can use to convert an email into a task, the only thing that needs to be changed is the email address in the script. For Asana this would not be necessary because the email address for converting an email into a taks is the same for all Asana users.

Comment: did you manage to find a way?